# Sending form action request to another project deployed on same server

Tags: java, rest, servlets

I have two projects dployed onmy tomcat server. I want to send the form action request(on submit) to a service written in the other project thats deployed on the same server.

something like :

```
<form method ="post" action="http://localhost:8081/simple-web-services/uploadQuestions" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h3>Choose your file : </h3> <br>
<input type ="file" name ="attachment"></input><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form
```

how can i make this work ??is it even allowed to do so ?

Comment: It should work. What error did you get?

Comment: 404 resource not found.It adds the current project name to the url.."/TestApp/simple-web-services/uploadQuestions" ..

Comment: The action must be a full url in your case.

Comment: I have used the full URL , on submit the url becomes..

Comment: http://localhost:8081/TestApp/simple-web-services/uploadQuestions

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not work as it will be rendered at `client` site (browser) which would not know anything about `localhost` or `port`. You will have to use the external url of that app in order to submit a `form` to it (e.g. `http://somehost.com/simple-web-services/uploadQuestions`).

If you dont't want to expose that endpoint at client site (or it's not available outside your `server` or `vpn`) then another approach might be to use your app's endpoint and call this `application`/`API` from inside your `server` side application using let's say Spring's `RestTemplate` or java's `HttpURLConnection`.